# Add #eecms Hashtag to Default Twitter Share Link?

Tags: feature-request

In order to give questions more exposure and to connect the Stack Exchange site to the community on Twitter, should we add the #eecms hashtag to the default message that is auto-generated from the "Share" link?

So instead of:

[image: Twitter share modal without #eecms hashtag]

It would be:

[image: Twitter share modal with #eecms hashtag]

Comment: A great idea, two thumbs up.

Comment: If this can be done, it should be.

Comment: I agree that this is a good idea. @anna-lear, is this possible?

Comment: I kind of thought this was already a convention. I know I do this, mostly because I want other #eecms followers to find my tweet.